# How to get the collection of all shapes in a powerpoint document?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I wonder if there is a way to get the collection of all shapes in a PowerPoint document analogous to `Document.Shapes` in Word.

According to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746621.aspx

> Use the Shapes property to return the Shapes collection. The following
>   example selects all the shapes in the active presentation.

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.SelectAll
```

But this will give me the Shapes only of the first Page/Slide, I think.

Comment: Have you ever used foreach? Foreach slide get the shapes and add them to a list declared outside the foreach

Comment: Thanks, yes I could use foreach, but when there is allways a property, which contains the document shapes, this is my preferred option. Since there could be many PowerPoint Documents with many slides through which I must to iterate, I think it could affect the performance of my AddIn.

Comment: Maybe there is a specific function to select all the shapes

Comment: The MSDN documentation is incorrect.  And ... " but when there is allways a property, which contains the document shapes, this is my preferred option"  There's no such property.

Answer (score 0):

No. Word and PowerPoint are different beasts with different workflows. 
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes, you will only get the shapes associated with the specfied slide.

As suggested you will need to iterate through the slide deck to create your own global list of shapes in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was:

```
  var allShapes = Application.GetActiveInstance().ActivePresentation.Slides.Range().Shapes;
```

It gives me back all Shapes of the PowerPoint presentation.